# cloudsim: How to compile source classes?

Tags: cloudsim

how i should compile and build classes of the sources folder!! (example datacenter.java or cloudlet.java .... )

To test ANT, I just extracted cloudsim from .zip and try to build without making any changes in any file.
I followed the instructions of readme.txt:

### Compiling CloudSim: using Ant

This release contains a simple buildfile for compiling CloudSim classes.
You need to have ant installed (http://ant.apache.org/).
Ant can be used in both Windows and Unix/Linux environment.

Usage:

- Being in the CloudSim root directory (cloudsim/), type 'ant' to compile all 
  cloudsim source files, put them into the classes/ directory and to create 
  a cloudsim-new.jar file in the jars/ directory
- Being in the CloudSim root directory (cloudsim/), type 'ant clean' to delete 
  all the compiled classes and the classes/ directory itself. The generated 
  cloudsim-new.jar is not deleted.

Still I ended up with 20 errors, even when trying to compile and build jar of cloudsim original classes with no modifications done.
Errors are in MathUtil class

Comment: I myself got the answer and is posting here which will help anyone who's facing the same problem. just add maths jar from here http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/download_math.cgi  and add it in jar folder and you are done

Comment: Instead of compiling source classes, you could have extended a source class and modified it according to your needs and used the new class in your project instead of the original class.